# What are the first couple terms of the Taylor series for the evolution of this network of capacitors and resistors?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, network

note: This is a computational problem, and I only need approximate accuracy, so the overall goal is, for a given accuracy and $\Delta t$ to compute the state of the system at $t+\Delta t$ to within said accuracy. If my approach is misguided, feel free to make that your answer.

I have a set of capacitors $\{C_i=(V_i(t),q_i(t),c_i=capacitance\}$ and a sparse set of resistors between pairs of capacitors $C_i,C_j$ with conductances $a_{ij}$.

the current in/out of any one Capacitor at time $t$ can be given by: $$\frac{d(q_i(t))}{dt}=\sum_{j=0}^{n}a_{ij}(V_j(t)-V_i(t))$$

$$ \frac{dV_i(t)}{dt}=\frac{dV_i(t)}{dq_i(t)}*\frac{dq_i(t)}{dt}=\frac{1}{c_i}*\sum_{j=0}^{n}a_{ij}(V_j(t)-V_i(t))$$

The second derivative looks like it's going to be a linear transformation of the first, or close enough to be computationally cost effective, but I'm not sure how to write this as a matrix equation, or even if my intuition is correct.

Comment: @Qmechanic, this is not a homework problem. and it is isomorphic to a problem in thermodynamics, didn't seem like a bad tag...

Comment: Hi Zackkenyon. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: Ah, well, I suppose I'm much more interested in the answer, but the question is about a method so it probably still applies.